# Wix UI for Installing Web sites

Tags: wix, wix3

Anyone have a WiX UI sequence for installing an ASP.Net Web site? Something that asks for a virtual dir, and app name similar to what the Visual Studio install projects do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked up an initial solution [here](http://blueonionsoftware.com/blog.aspx?p=3406b61d-8db0-4e89-b65c-3d804ede6e22).